# Existence of subgraphs with certain property

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let's take a look at the following two lemmas:

> **Lemma 1** (Large bipartite subgraph)
>
> Every $G$ has a bipartite subgraph with at least $e(G)/2$ edges.

> **Lemma 2** (Large average degree implies subgraph with large minimum degree)
>
> Let $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Every graph with average degree $2t$ has a
> subgraph with minimum degree greater than $t$.

I do not have any issues with the proofs of these lemmas since I was able understand them. But I am little confused about the statements.

*Regarding Lemma 1.* Am I right that we need to assume that bipartite subgraph should have at least one edge. Otherwise one can take a subgraph with empty edge set because it is vacuously true.

*Regarding Lemma 2.* Here we need to assume that $t>0$ (for $t=0$ the statement is false).  Also we need to assume that subgraph has nonempty vertex set (otherwise, it is vacuously true).

Is my reasoning correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Why would it be vacuously true that a subgraph of $G$ with $0$ edges has at least $e(G)/2$ edges? Unless $G$ happens to be an empty graph as well, this just seems false.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, ahh of course! Makes sense. What about my comment to Lemma 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lemma 1 does not need any special care. If $G$ has $0$ edges, then it is already bipartite and we can take the subgraph consisting of all of $G$, which has $0 \ge e(G)/2$ edges. If $G$ has $1$ or more edges, then $e(G)/2>0$ as well, and taking a $0$-edge subgraph won't help.

For Lemma 2, first of all you are definitely right that we should not allow $t=0$. Regarding whether the lemma is vacuously true for the $0$-vertex subgraph, it depends on whether you consider [the null graph to be a pointless concept](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007%2FBFb0066433). But the graph with no vertices is an exception to so many theorems that you should expect to take special care with it no matter what statement you find yourself reading.

Comment: Sorry but what is the difference between null and empty graph?

Comment: Terminology varies somewhat. Harary and Read use "null graph" to mean the graph with $0$ vertices. The words "empty graph" typically refer to a graph with as many vertices as you like, but $0$ edges; the complement of $K_n$ (which is often the "complete graph" but occasionally also called a "full graph"). Aside from linking to the paper, I've avoided using either term in my answer, to achieve as much clarity as possible.

Comment: Even if you admit the null graph as a subgraph, I suppose its "average degree" must be undefined.

Comment: Hi Misha, I read your answer very carefully! Even if I consider null graph $(\varnothing,\varnothing)$ to be a subgraph of graph $G$ with $d_{\text{ave}}(G)=2t \ (t>0)$, then minimum degree (which is denoted as $\delta(\cdot)$) of null graph is defined .

For any graph $H$ its minimum degree $\delta(H):=\min\limits_{v\in V(H)} \deg(v)$.  In our case $H=(\varnothing,\varnothing)$ and hence $V(H)=\varnothing$ and hence the statement $(\delta(H)>t)$ is vacuously true.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @ZFR I agree that it's vacuously true. (If I had to give the null graph $K_0$ a minimum degree, it would be $+\infty$.) But if you don't consider $K_0$ to be a graph at all, then it's not a problem!

Comment: Now I understand what you meant in your answer. It is really inconvenient to consider null graphs as a graphs. They are annoying and you need to take of them and adding some nontrivial conditions to theorems and statements.

Comment: Thank you Misha for your reply! I accept your answer! +1

Comment: P.S. Am I right that it is OK to consider empty graphs as a graph? By empty graph here I mean complement of $K_n$ for $n\geq 1$. I think that namely null graph is the most unpleasant case.

Comment: I think that almost everyone treats empty graphs ($\overline {K_n}$ for $n \ge 1$) as graphs these days, and I agree that they don't usually cause problems. If you're reading older sources, that's not as universal, and you may have to double-check. (In particular, if you identify a graph with its edge set, which some authors did, then you cannot even tell how many isolated vertices it has.)

Comment: Yeah, makes sense! Thanks a lot for your informative reply and constant help in my questions!